# Thumbs are not being displayed even image is there on the location in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gallery

I'm creating a gallery module, using CodeIgniter the upload functionality is working fine like I can find the images where they should be but I am unable to render them at the same time and the thumbnails are also appearing at the same time. This is the situation:
[image]

Here is my model code:

```
function get_images()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT picAlbumName FROM picAlbum");

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {

        $files = scandir($this->gallery_path . '/' . $row->picAlbumName);

        $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

    foreach($files as $file){
        $images [] = array (
            'url' => $this->gallery_path. '/' . $row->picAlbumName . '/' . $file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path. '/' .  $row->picAlbumName . '/' . 'thumbs/'. $file

        );
    }
    }

    print_r($images);

    return $images;
}
```

Controller:

```
    $data['images'] = $this->album_model->get_images();


    $this->load->view('album_view' , $data);
```

view:

```
   <?php if (isset($images) && count($images)): 
foreach($images as $images): ?>
 <div class="thumb">
        <a href="<?php echo $images['url']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $images['thumb_url']; ?>" />
                    </a>


                </div>
            <?php endforeach; else: ?>
<div id="blank_gallery">Please upload an image</div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Pictures are there in the folder, ive checked it twice. Kindly identify the mistake.

Comment: what is the value of `$this->gallery_path`?

Comment: $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH) . '/images';

Comment: if your APPPATH contains base_url, the just remove realpath. If not, then add base_url with APPPATH.

Comment: @MQ. Check your base_url

**config/constants.php**
`define('BASE_URL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');`

**config/config.php**
`$config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;`


**In Model or Controller**
`$this->gallery_path = base_url()."assets/images";`

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'url' and 'thumb_url' value of images array.

Also add your site's base url before image thumb_url.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/showcase/application/images/Nature/10011_10200942508307089_684217831_n.jpg 
[thumb_url]=>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/showcase/application/images/Nature/thumbs/10011_10200942508307089_684217831_n.jpg ) 
[1]=>Array([url]=>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/showcase/application/images/sunset/Lion.jpg 
[thumb_url]=>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/showcase/application/images/sunset/thumbs/Lion.jpg ) )

Answer (score 0):

I've find out the mistake actually i was not providing base_url() instead of it i was providing realpath().